# How to programmatically scroll umano SlidingUpPanelLayout dragview?

Tags: android, scroll, slide

I am using [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel.) by Umano

I have set the dragview as `sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/thumb"` using attribute.

Its working correctly but my problem is that I want to scroll this view from external scroll event from my main page.

How can I do this?

Is their any function to call in library?

There is `PanelSlideListener` but NO function to slide panel programmatically.

[image: description]

Right now I can only scroll from comments. I also want to enable scroll from image

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find anything for this? I also want to scroll panel programtically...

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set the State of the Panel:

```
 myPanel?.panelState = SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED
```

Answer (score 0):

This will scroll the sliding panel, but I'm not sure if it's what you need for dragView:

```
slideUpLayout.scrollableView.scrollTo(0, 0)
```